# My money is missing

Tags: lost-bitcoins, lost-transactions, cash-app

so on 7/19/23 two transactions happened to send to the same wallet
2 different amounts to start ended the same after fees and somehow 1 transaction was never received.  Wallet id was 100% accurate.

The txid shown on the 1 pic was also given to me as my hashid but how and only 1 transaction was received. Cashapp is not helping and i know the $ was only received 1x because i saw the wallet with my own eyes... someone help me cause cashapp is not

[image: cashapp mine (sent rush)]
[image: other system someone else's(sent priority)]

Comment: What do you see when you click that button labelled "View on Block Explorer"? Is there a transaction ID?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your deposit was received at the 1Nr address according to block explorers. So you should contact Binance (or Binance.US in the US) support to fix the balance for you.

Comment: Yeah, as this answer states, there were two payments to 1Nr2k…7oPn on the 19th. If only one has been credited, there is an accounting error on the side of the recipient. You’ll need to contact the customer service of the recipient.